# How do I get access to EC2 instance information from an ELB I have using C# Amazon SDK?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Using the .Net SDK from Amazon, How do I use C# interface to get an ELB I have and list its attached EC2 instances? important!: C#!!! Could not find any web documentation that describes it or how to get there...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for a function that finds the ELB containing a specific instance (according to it's ID)...:

public string GetELBNameThatInstanceBelongsTo(String InstanceId)
        {
            string lbName = "";
            try
            {
                DescribeLoadBalancersRequest lbRequest = new DescribeLoadBalancersRequest();
                DescribeLoadBalancersResponse lbResponse = ProductionELB.DescribeLoadBalancers(lbRequest);

```
            foreach (LoadBalancerDescription lbRes in lbResponse.DescribeLoadBalancersResult.LoadBalancerDescriptions)
            {
                // Load Instances
                for (int ii = 0; ii < lbRes.Instances.Count(); ii++)
                {
                    if (lbRes.Instances[ii].InstanceId == InstanceId)
                    {
                       lbName = lbRes.LoadBalancerName;
                       break;
                    }
                }

                if (lbName != "")
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonElasticLoadBalancingException ex)
        {
            //  Write an ERROR to log file
        }

        return lbName;
    }
```